# Issue with displaying fields horizontally on UCI CRM Form in CRM online version

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-uci

I want to have 8 fields displayed horizontally on a CRM Form, It works and displays in the classic UI.

However when I view in UCI, the fields are displayed one below the other i.e vertically

I created a 2- column Tab and added a 4 column section in it. However it doesn't work.

Is this the limitation of UCI. Is there any way I can achieve this? or any PCF control which I can use to display fields horizontally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually that is the purpose of UCI - responsive layout. Based on the available real estate - the controls will reflow you give great User experience across PC browser, tablet and mobile devices without scrollbars.

In case of your need, you may need to develop custom PCF control with overridden CSS stylesheet to maintain the position of controls in a container. Something like [this github repo](https://gist.github.com/thomaspark/8969079).